# Extra space - where does it come from?

Tags: border, padding, margin, space, thickness

I was fiddling around with this example
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_clientleft_clienttop
It looked like the top picture below, having a space between the top border and the text.

I then changed the code to a top border thickness of 0px. Looked like the second picture below.
No space now. Hmm. What was the extra space in the top figure? Margins? I then set padding and margins to 0px as well. No change.
I then set the top border width to 1px. And now the entire space came back. Like on the bottom picture below.

Can anyone explain that?

Thanks
Poul

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The p tag automatically creates some space before and after itself. So, for the case of border thickness to 0px
[image: The p tags margin are getting added outside the div]
So, we are not able to see the top margin here.

Comment: The topmargin of what element? Why would it influence the <p> that I removed a border of an confining <div>?
But I didn't know about the extra space non-margin/non-padding whitespace introduced by the <p>. Does that mean you cannot ever remove the whitespace from a <p>-statement? I just assumed that the <p>'s used whatever margin/paddings used by the line it was inserted in. Is that wrong?

Comment: You can add style to the <p> tag with the required margin and the <p> tag has default CSS that you can see in the shared image (user agent stylesheet)

Comment: No, sorry, but I do not understand. A border has no extra space, and only consists of the border itself. So the only visible influence if I add or remove a border, should be the border itself. I think. :-)